# While loop with two conditions

Tags: php, mysql

This while loop is supposed to continue until the end of the array or until counter reaches 6, what am I doing wrong here?

```
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultSet, MYSQL_ASSOC) && ($counter < 6))
        {
        ?>

    <?php echo $row['Item_NAME'] ?>

<img style="width:250px; height:250px;" src="<?php {echo "{$row['Item_IMAGE']}";} ?>">

    <?php $counter = $counter + 1;
    ?>
        <?php
        }
```

Works without the `&& ($counter < 6)`but shows the wrong number of images, adding this will show the correct number of boxes (where the images should be) but not retrieve the images or names from the array.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you just add a LIMIT to your SQL query?

Comment: Or break; inside the loop? `!($counter < 6)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't you just use `break;` inside, when the second condition isn't true anymore?

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultSet, MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
    if($counter > 5){
        break;
    }
    ?>

    <?php echo $row['Item_NAME'] ?>

    <img style="width:250px; height:250px;" src="<?php {echo "{$row['Item_IMAGE']}";} ?>">

    <?php $counter = $counter + 1;
    ?>
    <?php
    }
```

Comment: `if(!($counter < 6))`  === `if($counter>5)`

Comment: True! This was just my 30seconds answer, but you're very right! I'm correcting this immediately..